# Can we get a logo and a header?

Tags: feature-request, design

I know, *I know ...,* this question has been asked so many times on so many Stack Exchange sites and has been answered that there will be no custom themes anymore.

I've been following this site since its proposal in 2015, through the final graduation in 2017. In 2019 there was a facelift of all the default-themed sites. I'm *not* asking for a custom theme for Ethereum.

All I want to know is, **is it possible to get a logo and a header?** No styling or revamp of the theme required, just some custom artwork. Maybe as a small gift of acknowledgment after running a healthy Stack Exchange site for <del>five</del> <del>six</del> seven years? :-)

Thanks for considering it.

---

Edit: Yearly bump (2021)!

The five most active StackExchange sites that do not have a custom theme:

1. **Ethereum** 27 questions/day
2. Data Science 22 questions/day
3. Law 13 questions/day
4. Islam 9.4 questions/day
5. Biblical Hermeneutics 9.2 questions/day

---

Edit: Yearly bump (2022)!

The five most active StackExchange sites that do not have a custom theme:

1. **Ethereum** 32 questions/day
2. Data Science 20 questions/day
3. Substrate 10 questions/day (new)
4. Law 9.6 questions/day
5. Economics 6.7 questions/day

I'm wondering if there will be ever any official answer to this thread.

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from yesterday: [Custom Ethereum design and logo - Information gathering](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/697/79828) :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Proposal A**: Ethereum Logo embedded with a speech bubble.

[image: black and white]
[image: black and blue]
[image: turquoise and blue]

Comment: I like this design. I think I would find it even nicer if the diamond had the ETH2.0 coloring (https://ethereum.org/static/c48a5f760c34dfadcf05a208dab137cc/31987/eth-diamond-rainbow.png)

Comment: @q9f Very nice! Did you see https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/706/site-design-and-logo-draft ?

Comment: No, that's pretty cool!

Answer (score 6):

**Proposal C:** Ethereum Speech Bubbles

[image: green on blue]

[image: green on blue with text]

Answer (score 2):

**Proposal B:** Stack Exchange Diamonds

[image: black and white]

[image: blue and turquoise]

[image: turquoise and white]

Answer (score 2):

**Proposal D:** Ethereum Diamond Sailor

[image: turquoise on white]

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if anyone else agrees with me, but I figure we might be able to tell with the upvotes: I sort of like the completely unstyled site in a weird sort of way. So I guess if you're all for leaving this as vanilla as possible on purpose, upvote.

Comment: Hmm, -1 so far. Maybe it is just me.