# A suggestion for the site's logo

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

> Related to [Can we get a logo and a header?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/650/can-we-get-a-logo-and-a-header).

I actually like this site even if I have no thoughts for Ethereum, and seeing that it doesn't have a logo at all, I think it's about time to propose a suggestion for one.

We know that the original Ethereum logo is not usable. How about try customizing it a bit. That's exactly what was done in Blender SE's logo.

[image: Blender SE Logo]

<sup>It's the Blender logo, but turned into a speech bubble.</sup>

We could do something similar with the Ethereum logo.

Here's one I made using MS Paint:

[image: Custom Ethereum Logo]

Looks quite good, not gonna lie.

What do you suggest to make the logo?

---

Here are some questions you might ask from me:

> **Why are you wanting this?**

For me, I think it is time to actually give Ethereum SE its own style along with the others.

> **Nice proposal, what's with the logo though? Why did you even make a custom logo?**

The logo is basically the top of the actual Ethereum logo (the only customization I can think of to make it look good). Also, the logo is custom, and is actually what I am going to use [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358936/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2021/359100#359100), but now that I'm suspended once again, I can't really edit to add more masks. I want to edit it using an alt account, however, but I don't want to risk abusing.

> **Do you have a custom theme for this site?**

Well, no. I only want to try and give Ethereum some new style, like an actual logo.

Comment: I think the main issue is that we're not allowed a custom theme, or, therefore, a logo... :-\

Comment: Unless you have the authority to get us one...

Comment: Is that related to administrative rights? If other communities do have, I guess we also deserve to have one ;) not sure how this is managed across communities and whether there are some 'super' admins that manage the rest.