# New site design launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, the new design just went live! At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/706/site-design-and-logo-draft).

I have really enjoyed working with you all to create this theme. Thank you for being an awesome community, and I hope you enjoy the new design!

Comment: Looks stunning. Great job!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Not sure if I'm missing something, but shouldn't gold and bronze badge colours be switched?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yep! That's a bug :)

Comment: Looks like it's been resolved now :)

Comment: Well only on the main site - On the meta site, it's still there.

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake: Looks like it's now resolved on the Meta site as well? :)

Comment: @V2Blast yeah, it is :)